# Python - find a value in DataFrame and update it

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

**Preface:** Using Google Colab. I read a data from a CSV file and printed it out (as you can see below). It is big enough so that it doesn't allow me to view the entire table.

**Goal:** I want to find where the 'price' == 0 under the 'price' column, and then update that value to be 9.99. I could find the location of this value myself by simply looking in the Excel file and updating the price at that specific location in Python, but I want to be able to code it up as if I didn't have the time to do that.

That is, I could simply write `data.at[index, 'price'] = 9.99`, but I want to write it generally so that the program will (1) find it and then (2) update it for me. In addition, the rows in my Excel file are off, so it's even more confusing. The Excel table skips the number (row) 81 for some reason.

I need a for loop? This is an INTRO CLASS, so please don't do something totally unnecessary that I won't understand. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can display the zero rows with:

```
print(data[data['price'] == 0])
```

Give them a new value with:

```
data.loc[data['price'] == 0, 'price'] = 9.99
```

Comment: Would this also work?
`for i in range(data.shape[0]):
  if data['price'][i] == 0:
    print(data.at[i, 'price'])
    data['price'][i] = 9.99
    print(data.at[i, 'price'])`

Comment: Larry Wall says "there's more than one way to skin a cat." You told me you have a dataframe, so I gave the canonical ways to access it, pushing both loops down into C code supplied by pandas. If you want to have python grovel over `.iterrows()` or similar, sure, go for it. Understand that when there's many rows, it _will_ be slower.

Comment: Now, what if I now want to update a value (string) under the 'type' column? I want to change the row that has 'Market Value Paperback' as its 'type' to just 'Paperback'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df.loc[df['price'] == 0, 'price'] = 9.99
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html